# Simple Injector - inject container property

Tags: c#, containers, ioc-container, simple-injector

I want to inject Container property via SimpleInjector. I didn't find any functionality of SimpleInjector for that.

Then I wanted to register self container to itself, but Container has no interface.

I want this functionality because I don't to transfer Container object via constructor - because why if I can use auto inject of register objects.

My usage idea:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.AutowirePropertiesWithAttribute<InjectableProperty>();
container.Register<ISomething, Something>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

ISomething:

```
public interface ISomething 
{
   void SomeMethod();
}
```

Something class:

```
public class Something : ISomething 
{
    public void SomeMethod() 
    {
       var environment = _container.GetInstance<IEnvironment>();
       environment.DoSomething();
    }

    [InjectableProperty] // - maybe it is not possible (I don't know it)
    Container Container {get;set;}
}
```

Do you have any idea to achieve that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Example code added...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prevent having your application code depend upon the container. The only place in your application that should know about the existence of your DI library is the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) (the place where you register all your dependencies).

Instead of letting each class call back into the container (which is called the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)), prefer using Dependency Injection. With Dependency Injection you inject dependencies instead of asking for them.

So you can rewrite your class to the following:

```
public class Something : ISomething 
{
    private readonly IEnvironment environment;

    public Something (IEnvironment environment)
    {
       this.environment = environment;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
       this.environment.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Also, prevent doing any logic in your constructors besides storing the incoming dependencies. This allows you to [compose object graphs with confidence](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

In some cases however, it can still be useful to inject the `Container` into another class. For instance when creating a factory class that is located *inside* the Composition Root. In that case you can still use constructor injection, like this:

```
// Defined in an application layer
public interface IMyFactory
{
    IMyService CreateService();
}

// Defined inside the Composition Root
public class MyFactory : IMyFactory
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public MyFactory(Containter container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IMyService CreateService(ServiceType type)
    {
        return type == ServiceType.A
            ? this.container.GetInstance<MyServiceA>()
            : this.container.GetInstance<MyServiceB>();
    }
}
```

If Simple Injector detects a `Container` constructor argument, it will inject itself into the constructor automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is correct answer for me! I guess the first SomeMethod with environment param is mistake and it is constructor, isn't it?

Comment: @Frk: That should have been the constructor. Fixed it.

Comment: Hello Mister @Steven, so can I use the container inside the factory to create instances of previous registered service , but how can I be aware to avoid other devs to do "Compositions" stuff inside the factory ?

Comment: "If Simple Injector detects a Container constructor argument, it will inject itself into the constructor. There's nothing you have to do about this." => This last line is useful.